# Adding a dynamic number of tags in LXML

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have the following codesnippet:

```
from lxml import etree
dataset = etree.Element("trace_data")
# create childs of dataset
pinfo   = etree.SubElement(dataset, "pinfo")
pinfo.text = processinfo
traces  = etree.SubElement(dataset, "traces")

#enumerate over all traces, create a subelement to the traces element with an index for every element
for index,trace in enumerate(traces):
    trace_xml       = etree.SubElement(traces,str(index))
    trace_xml.text  = trace
```

Which, to my confusion, does not fill the subelements of traces, but generates an XML like:

```
<trace_data><pinfo>1</pinfo><traces/></trace_data>
```

Even though I meant it to iterate over a list of strings, called trace, then add a tag for each of the elements in the list:

```
<trace_data><pinfo>1</pinfo><traces><trace1>"test"</trace1><trace2>"test2"</trace2</traces></trace_data>
```

and so on

I suspect that this may come from the way I am trying to create subelements for the traces tag.

What are some ways to create a subelement to the tag traces for each element in the list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:

processinfo always contains a numeric value, e.g. 1
LXML doesnt allow tags to start with a number and therefore throws an error.

I couldn't see this error due to poor exceptionhandling.